# Express the following in the form x + iy.

Tags: complex-analysis

Express the following in the form $x+iy$:

$$\frac{a+ib}{a-ib}-\frac{a-ib}{a+ib}$$
and
$$\frac{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}+ia}{a-i\sqrt{1+a^{2}}}$$

Both expressions need to be in the form $x+iy$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please [do not use image for the essential part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/356647) of the question. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part (a):
Break into two parts.
We have

$$\frac{a + ib}{a - ib}$$

we want to make the denominator real, so multiply both the numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of $a - ib$ which is $a + ib$

$$\frac{a + ib}{a - ib} \cdot \frac{a + ib}{a + ib} = \frac{a^2 + 2iab  - b^2}{a^2 + b^2} = \frac{a^2 - b^2}{a^2 + b^2} + i\frac{2ab}{a^2 + b^2}$$

which is now in the form $x' + iy'$ with $x' = \frac{a^2 - b^2}{a^2 + b^2}$ and $y' = \frac{2ab}{a^2 + b^2}$.

Now do the next bit just the same which gives $x' - iy'$. Then altogether we get

$$x' + iy' - (x' - iy') = 2y'$$

So we have $x + iy$, where $x = 0$ and $y = \frac{4ab}{a^2 + b^2}$.

You can do the same thing again for part (b), it's just a little more complex.